# How to make an outbound call in Twilio with Java, using TwiML and not a URL?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I'm looking to make an outbound call in a Java application using Twilio. All of the tutorials I found used a static TwiML file hosted on a URL. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to pass in TwiML as a parameter for an outgoing call.

I found this on this link, but it doesn't explain how to dynamically render TwiML: https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-in-java#where-to-next

> Of course, the TwiML you use to make the outbound call doesn't need to be a static file like in this example. Server-side Java code that you control can dynamically render TwiML to use for the outbound call.

I've tried the following:

```
PhoneNumber to = new PhoneNumber(toPhone); // Replace with your phone number
PhoneNumber from = new PhoneNumber(fromPhone); // Replace with a Twilio number
TwiML twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
        .say(new Say.Builder(message).build())
        .build();
Call call = Call.creator(to, from, twiml.toXml()).create(client);
```

While the `Call.creator()`has some overloaded methods of `(PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber, String)`, none of them will accept TwiML, nor XML.

How do make an outbound call in Java using TwiML?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot [make an outbound call with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls) and directly pass the TwiML that you want the call to follow at the same time.

When you make the outbound call you need to pass a URL. That URL does not have to return static TwiML though. If you want to return dynamic TwiML you need to set the URL for the call to a URL of a web application that can respond to the request with TwiML.

It might make it more obvious what I mean if you check out some of the dynamic tutorials. This one on [building an automated phone survey](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/automated-survey-java-spring) dynamically generates the next question and takes input from the user in response. This [click to call implementation in Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/click-to-call-java-spring) also dynamically generates the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) when the call connects.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your question and Phil's answer are over four years old; however, one can place outbound calls with Twilio and directly pass the TwiML that you want the call to follow concurrently, starting in Twilio version 3.39.0 as shown here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/releases/tag/3.39.0. One can now opt the URL for TwiML starting in this release.